# Softer term for gaslighting - as in, trying to make someone constantly think they're wrong?

Tags: synonyms, terminology

I"m aware of the term "gaslighting", but I believe this only references when someone else is trying to make you think you're going mad; but I'm wondering is there a similar term that explains when someone is doing much the same, but in this instance is trying to make you constantly doubt your intelligence on the matter and acts as if their opinion on the matter is infallible, based on just their word?

Comment: Gaslighting is a pretty soft and subtle term. Few people are familiar with the movie it comes from and no one understands the limitations of gas light that made the meaning possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potentially [undermine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/undermine)

> to make someone less confident, less powerful, or less likely to succeed, or to make something weaker, often gradually

Comment: Yes; _unstring_ and especially _unhinge_ are blunter. This is appropriate.

Comment: I think this one suits my situation best :)

Answer (score 0):

A word that comes to mind for me is *enervate*

> *enervate*: to reduce the mental or moral vigor of ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enervate))
>
> [Some Examples](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&safe=strict&biw=1486&bih=782&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1941%2Ccd_max%3A2004%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk00wdLbw08qLhml4t-BbEo_FO6VWgw%3A1607744092971&ei=XDrUX47UOpjStQaf-Jv4Dg&q=%22enervate%20her%22&oq=%22enervate%20her%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i333k1.2080.2080.0.2397.1.1.0.0.0.0.134.134.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.133....0.jDLsCSK7mfM)

Another, really fun word, is *unstring*

> *unstring*: To deprive of composure or emotional stability; unnerve. ([Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=unstring))

Comment: Got any examples of 'enervate' in this form? I've never seen or heard 'he/she enervates him/her', though 'I found the music enervating' is common enough. 'He unstrings her' is a new one on me!!

Comment: @Old Brixtonian I just added a link with some examples.

Comment: _enervate_ connotes a different type of _weakening_ and isn't appropriate to the context at hand. _unstring_ ( a new one on me as well) is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I offer **unhinge**, which carries with it strong connotations of *mentally unbalancing* someone.

Here is how AHD defines the word—

> To confuse or disrupt: an event that unhinged the marriage.

> To derange or unbalance: He was unhinged by his wife's death.